# Why does my code work one way in Mathematica and another way in PlayerPro?

Tags: cdf-format, windows, dialog-window

I wrote the following simple code and deployed it as a `CDF`.

```
   Button["Ok", (SystemDialogInput["FileSave", ".PDF"])]
```

If I open the `CDF` file in *Mathematica* and click on the button, it brings up this dialog:

[image]

If I open the `CDF` file in MathematicaPlayerPro and click on the button, it brings up a different dialog:

[image]

How can I get the same dialog from MathematicaPlayerPro as I get from  *Mathematica*?

Comment: This looks like a bug and you might want to wait until MathematicaPlayer Version 9 is out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is a difference between Mathematica and the Player Pro but between Mathematica 8 and 9. For me Mathematica 8 brings up the same dialog as Player Pro 8, while Mathematica 9 brings up something slightly different (my interpretation is that WRI has improved the automatic behavior, I'm not sure whether I'd call the old behavior to be wrong or a bug...). I would be very surprised when Player Pro 9 will, once it is available, not behave as Mathematica 9 does...

You can enforce Version 8 (and 7 and 6 as well) for both Mathematica and Player Pro to show what Version 9 shows by default with additional specifications, as e.g. here:

```
Button["Ok", (SystemDialogInput["FileSave", {".PDF",
    {"PDF-Files" -> {"*.pdf"}, "All Files" -> {"*"}}}])]
```

Comment: Note that on Mac V8 this also does not display correctly due to a bug. This has been fixed in V9.

Answer (score 1):

I don't  know about Player Pro but a CDF generally has some restrictions as outlined in [the documentation center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html):

#### Interactivity in .cdf Files

- Almost all of the functions available in Mathematica can be used to build applications for CDF Player, but there are a few programming restrictions to keep in mind.
- All interactive content must be generated with the Manipulate command and may only use mouse-driven elements, such as Slider, Locator, Checkbox, PopupMenu, etc.
- Dialog windows are not supported.
- MathLink operations, including J/Link and .NET/Link, are not supported.
- **Data import and export are not supported** from within CDF Player with the exception of Wolfram-curated data sources (ChemicalData, CountryData, WordData, etc.).

Since it doesn't supports exports I can imagine that a "SaveAs" dialog doesn't make sense either, so I'm not surprised by this dialog box behaving differently (I'm actually surprised you get one at all).

Comment: you are of course correct that a "Save As" dialog doesn't make much sense when no exports are possible. Nevertheless the dialog is there and comes up just as for Mathematica and Player Pro even when looking at a CDF document with the free CDF-Player. Only a call to `Export` will fail...

Answer (score 1):

On Mac it always comes up as "All Files". I presume the "All Files"/"PDF" distinction is what you are noting although it looks like the home directory on Windows differs as well whereas on Mac it does not.

This is a grab from Player Pro:

[image]

The default representation as `".PDF...." is a bug I believe (had a back and forth with tech support about this sort of thing a couple of years ago).

In Mathematica 8 the only difference is by default the file directory is expanded -- i.e. the button I have circled is pressed.

In Mathematica 9 something weird has happened -- they have fixed the filename display bug but looks like that have doubled up on panelling!

[image]

The upshot is that these differences between Player Pro and Mathematica are small and do not impede usage.